# Why couldn't the Merovingian have predicted his wife's betrayal?

Tags: the-matrix

Since the Merovingian had precognitive abilities similar to the Oracle's, why couldn't he have predicted his wife would betray him?

I think he had the power of mind (code) reading, just like the Oracle.

Answer (score 27):

**He didn't have the same precognitive abilities as the Oracle.**

He is a crime lord and is a "trafficker of information". He smuggles programs out and is generally in the loop about the goings on around the Matrix through his exiled programs and crime syndicate. Therefore he couldn't predict his wife would betray him, but he was told by his goons.

> He actually wants the abilities, the "eyes of the Oracle", which is the precognitive ability to "see" into the future, in exchange for Neo in *The Matrix Revolutions*.

Comment: "In the loop" ha! :)

Comment: @Toby whats the joke? i wanna laugh too :(

Comment: The Merovingian, as with all Matrix native constructs, is supposedly a program. Programs use loops. In fact most very low-level programs, even OS's or maybe the Matrix can at an abstracted level be thought of as  one big super loop that sits and waits for things to happen. Thus the Merovingian being "in the loop" is an unintentional pun, albeit not the greatest but it gave me a moment's humour.

Comment: @Toby Having a compsci degree, I should have seen it xD now i geddit lelelel

Answer (score 11):

I won't mark spoilers (it would be messy). Reader beware.

---

He did not have prediction powers "like the oracle". He had a enormous informer/information network.

The oracle probably also did not have prediction powers, just a very sophisticated heuristics program with WhatTheBytes(TM) of previous data on human behaviour (she has been studying humans - and probably the chosen - since the first version of the matrix, or even before).

So, that cleared, why didn't he predict the betrayal? It could be several factors, such as:

- **Ego**: His self-image is of the ultimate gallant charmer. He thinks he can get any female he wants, and could never think one of them could betray him. So until the consummated fact slapped in in the face like a MIRC large trout, he was blinded.
- **Spite**: he sees her as a (*used*) toy, a decorative figure. The way he speaks of the cake lady, shows how low he thinks of females. To him they are basic, primitive, lower lifeforms.
- **Could not be predicted because it happened in the heat of the moment.** Probably her betrayal wasn't a longstanding plan. As she tells Neo in the bathroom, she got envious of his relationship with Trinity because the bond between them reminded her of her early days with Merovingian. So she probably decided to betray him during the dinner party, possibly when he excused himself to make out with the lipstick lady.
- **Manipulation by the Architect.** Getting the Keymaker is crucial to getting into the Architect room. Getting into the architect room is crucial to reboot the matrix and continue the plan. Being a mastermind manipulator, the Architect could've well sowed the seeds (fake info) here and there to "script" the events.

So it could've been a classic egomaniacal villain flaw. Just like Superman, when Luthor's token female decoration decided to remove the Kryptonite from his neck.

Comment: `Probably her betrayal wasn't a longstanding plan.` not to mention it didn't seem to have a longstanding effect... they appear to have made up by the time Trinity and the gang held up Club Hel.

Comment: @Michael see bullet #1. Actually it is shown on-screen Mero cursing (in french, obviously) and a "now we are even" smirk on her face. Even if she is a toy, it is his *favorite* toy.